# Element type “GridLayout” must be followed by either attribute specifications, “>” or “/>” in eclipse

Tags: android

hello dears my android application code creates the following errors at the same line that i have put the + sign. 
here is the code

```
          <GridLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

          +  <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:width="70dp"
                android:height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:onClick="sevenbtn"
                android:text="7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
```

1. Element type “GridLayout” must be followed by either attribute specifications, “>” or “/>”
2. Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

how can i solve these errors please give me ur suggestions

Comment: That first message is spot-on, you forgot to close the start tag.

Answer (score 0):

@Goitom

You missed to close the GridLayout before adding the buttons inside it.

Please refer to this:

```
<GridLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:width="70dp"
            android:height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:onClick="sevenbtn"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            ... />

</GridLayout>
```